Applying Magnetic Field Boundary Conditions Across a Curved Interface
I am trying to determine how magnetic fields behave across the interface between two media with different material properties. The challenge arises because the boundary surface between the two media is curved and not planar. Specifically, the surface normal at the interface depends on one of the coordinates, making it unclear how to calculate and apply the boundary conditions effectively.
How can I determine the magnetic field in the second medium under such conditions? What is the correct approach to handle a surface whose normal is position-dependent?

The tangential component of H and the normal component of B are continuous across any macroscopic surface that has a tangent plane and a normal vector. If it is a discrete apex or a ridge where there is no tangent plane, e.g., a cone or a cube, then you can always approximate the non-smooth portions by smooth surface pieces.
